# how to add exception handling during inference with hugging face?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, torch

I'm trying to download a model from hugging face and run a inference. I'm new to torch library, can someone point me to it's documentation . basedon sample code below,

```
with torch.no_grad()
  ...
```

trying to add some exception handling to this code. not sure , what the above line does , but is there any exception in the torch library that i can use to catch , if there is an exception, if the above line fails.

```
import torch
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, DistilBertForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")
model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**inputs).logits

predicted_class_id = logits.argmax().item()
model.config.id2label[predicted_class_id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off,

> not sure, what the above line does

`with torch.no_grad()` disables gradient calculation. That means, Tensors aren't stored during the gradient calculations of your loss. This can speed up inference and uses less memory.

See the docs for more info about it: 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html

---

> Is there any exception in the torch library that I can use to catch, if there is an exception, if the above line fails?

PyTorch itself doesn't provide utilities for such exception handling. You can use a normal [Try/Except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) but this shouldn't be necessary because `torch.no_grad()` doesn't raise exceptions. If you're worried about the logic within the block, you can simply wrap it inside a `try`:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    try:
        logits = model(**inputs).logits
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        # exit, some fallback or check the type of the error
# ...
```